# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to Custom Class

Tags: java

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: my.app, PID: 15441
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to my.app.ChatNotificationHashSet
at my.app.UserHandler.getChatNotificationMessage(UserHandler.java:127)
at my.app.NotificationUtil.getChatTitle(NotificationUtil.java:100)
at my.app.NotificationUtil.showChat(NotificationUtil.java:71)
at my.app.service.GCMListenerService.onMessageReceived(GCMListenerService.java:47)
at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzq(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzp(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**ChatNotificationHashSet**

```
public class ChatNotificationHashSet<E> extends LinkedHashSet<String> {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**UserHandler (where the exception occurs)**

```
public ChatNotificationHashSet<String> getChatNotificationMessage() {
        return (ChatNotificationHashSet<String>) pref.getStringSet(CHAT_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, null); // <- Exception occurs here
    }

    public void setChatNotificationMessage(ChatNotificationHashSet<String> messages) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putStringSet(CHAT_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, messages);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

---

How can this happen? There shouldn't be any problems when casting `null` to `ChatNotificationHashSet<String>`, right? I couldn't think of any other problem.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `getStringSet()` ? It seems that it doesn't return `ChatNotificationHashSet`.

Comment: It's androids `SharedPreferences` class (http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/SharedPreferences.java/?v=source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Set` that is returned by `getStringSet()` does not need to be the same as you pass to `SharedPreferences.Editor.putStringSet()` method. It's generally up to internal implementation. I assume it serializes the data and puts it into some storage and unserializes when retrieving back.

If you need your specific structure, it's probably better to implement some wrapper which would either read all settings in the constructor or retrieve the settings on demand from underlying `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

`pref.getStringSet()` returns a `HashSet` and not your class, even when it can handle your class as `HashSet` while saving.

Answer (score 1):

Values are simply copied into an existing HashSet. Your collection is only a source for the copy.

Refer the comments on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13446387/1364747

> Interface used for modifying values in a SharedPreferences object. All
>   changes you make in an editor are batched, and not copied back to the
>   original SharedPreferences until you call commit() or apply()
>   Source: [SharedPreferences.Editor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

Only after commit changes are copied to the original SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Exception came in your program with this line

```
 return (ChatNotificationHashSet<String>) pref.getStringSet(CHAT_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, null); // <- Exception occurs here
```

because your `ChatNotificationHashSet` class is a Strict-Type Argument (simply say generics Supported). So `Type-Safety` is enabled for this class.

Here `getStringSet` method return the Object of Type `java.util.HashSet<String>` which is not a type of  `ChatNotificationHashSet<String>`.

So, Converting a `HashSet<String>` type Object to `ChatNotificationHashSet<String>` will prone to `ClassCastException` as You see in your Code

Comment: Generics has nothing to do with the error. The object being returned is not a  ChatNotificationHashSet. Its a basic java util HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I've chosen to save the list as an simple JSON String, which works fine.

Comment: You could probably accept one of the answers, because some of them did answer why the ClassCastException happened.