# Android ArrayList<String> stored not restored back to its saved sorted order

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, sharedpreferences, store

1. I have an myArrayList which is to be stored and restored back in its saved sorted order. But the code does not do that. Why?

   ```
   ArrayList<String> myArrayList

   // save:
           SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
           .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
   SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
   edit = prefs.edit();
   edit.putStringSet("mydata", new LinkedHashSet<String>(myArrayList));
   edit.commit();

       // read:
   myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(PreferenceManager
           .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).getStringSet(
                   "mydata", new LinkedHashSet<String>()));
   adapterAppList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
           myArrayList);
   ```
2. Is there any better way I can store the value of myArrayList and restored back to its original saved sorted order?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45035904/7746134

Comment: you can't save an object in SharedPreferences. you can convert the object to a string then save it and convert string to object at fetching.

Comment: Not possible:" can't save an object in SharedPreferences" because I can get the data back but not in its original order

Comment: You can serialize arrayList like string with gson

Comment: HashSet() cannot be used because it has no order, that is why I change to LinkedHashSet()

Comment: I don't know how to convert ArrayList  to a string and back. Please let me know.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` is handling that as a plain `Set`, which has no order, inherently. It doesn't care what implementation you use, but even though you're using an ordered `Set`, it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize arrayList like string:

1 with gson

```
public ArrayList<String> convertToArrayList(String json) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(json)){
        return null; // or new ArrayList<>()
    }
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
}
public String convertFromArrayList(ArrayList<String> list) {
    if (list == null){
        return null;
    }
    return new Gson().toJson(list);
}
```

2 without gson

```
public ArrayList<String> convertToArrayList(String st) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(st)){
        String[] str = st.split(",");
        if (str.length > 0){
            return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
public String convertFromArrayList(ArrayList<String> list) {
    if (list!=null && !list.isEmpty()){
        return TextUtils.join(",", list);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: convertToArrayList() breaks if I pass in an empty string

Comment: when I call convertFromArrayList(), 
I get following error:
(I am using a jar on eclipse)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/gson/Gson;

Comment: you need to add Gson lib to your project
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.2/

Comment: the crash is fixed because I use a copy of 2.6.2

Comment: when I call convertFromArrayList(), 
Gson().toJson(list) still crash 

the value of list is 
[a1, a2 , a3]

No error displayed.

Comment: I break into parts: Gson gson = new Gson(); 
  String json = gson.toJson(list);
  return json;
and it crash at  Gson gson = new Gson();

Comment: try new GsonBuilder().create() instead new Gson()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204189/discussion-between-mr-chan-and-kalugin1912).

Comment: The procedure without gson version is used as I am using eclipse + jar. The new Gson().toJson(list) will crash my app.

Answer (score 3):

HashSet is not keeping orders, it is ordering for quickest find to it.
 You can convert list to json and save as string.
When you need to it, you can convert it to ArrayList from json with keeped ordering.
Example:

```
String listAsString = new Gson().toJson(arrayList); //list to string
List<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(listAsString,String[].class)) //string to list
```

dont forget add library to build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, the order is not stored in string set, coz it is a set (duh).
When I was bugged with this, I got the serializing solution where, you can serialize your string.

**Read this only if you haven't read about serializing, else go down and read my hack**

*In order to store array items in order, we can serialize the array into a single string (by making a new class ObjectSerializer  (copy the code from – www.androiddevcourse.com/objectserializer.html , replace everything except the package name))*

*Entering data in Shared preference :*
[image]

*the rest of the code on line 38 -* [image]

*Put the next arg as this, so that if data is not retrieved it will return empty array(we cant put empty string coz the container/variable is an array not string)*

**Coming to my Hack :-**

Merge contents of array into a single string by having some symbol in between each item and then split it using that symbol when retrieving it.
If you are worried about splitting just look up "splitting a string in java".

[Note: This works fine if the contents of your array is of primitive kind like string, int, float, etc. It will work for complex arrays which have its own structure, suppose a phone book, but the merging and splitting would become a bit complex. ]

PS: I am new to android, so don't know if it is a good hack, so lemme know if you find better hacks.