# Storing Multiple Numbers in SharedPreferences without having specific keys

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm gonna store some cell-numbers so that I can use them in AutoCompleteTextView later, so my problem is that if I store the numbers using same key the value will be over-written, any suggestion or alternatives?

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175880/how-can-i-store-an-integer-array-in-sharedpreferences ?

Comment: yeah just like that, thank you man

Answer (score 2):

You can't store different value for same key, so better you should use Sqlite.