# Android - Sharedpreferences Collect Data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I generate a random number when I open the application and I save this number with Sharedpreferences. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Random r = new Random();
        int number = r.nextInt(100);

        SharedPreferences randomnumber = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = randomnumber.edit();
        editor.putInt("intValue",number);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Can I collect old and new numbers when I open the application?

Comment: use `getInt` on `randomnumber` to fetch your data

Comment: I want to collect old and new data in each record @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: show us an example of what exactly you want

Comment: I think you would be better of using an SQLite table as you can add new numbers rather than overwriting existing values - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding the old value with the new value with this

```
editor.putInt("intValue",number);
```

That's why you will always see one value for it. You could either have different field names or use an array for example like this [How can I store an integer array in SharedPreferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175880/how-can-i-store-an-integer-array-in-sharedpreferences)

Answer (score 1):

Get old value before it set new value..

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int number = r.nextInt(100);

    SharedPreferences randomnumber = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    String old = randomnumber.getString('intValue');  // old value

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = randomnumber.edit();
    editor.putInt("intValue",number); // set new value
    editor.apply();
```