# Remembering the previous array from shared preference

Tags: java, android, arrays, sharedpreferences

Just a quick question regarding sharedPreferences and int arrays. This is some of my code (the relevant bits). And what I want to happen is if the user does something (keeping it vague because it is not relevant), then the array keeps a 2 in that position. Instead what happens is if everytime I close the app or change the activity, the array goes back to being all ones with no twos. This might be a trivial problem, sorry if it is.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int[] list = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

public void startAQuestion(View view){ 

    checkAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) { 

                if(editText2.getText().toString().equals(mAnswer)) {

                    list[tappedQuestionmark]=2; 

                    storeIntArray("updateList", list);

                    Log.i("The array is ", Arrays.toString(list));
                }    
            }
            });
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        int[] isCorrect = getFromPrefs("updateList");

        Log.i("is Correct is ", Arrays.toString(isCorrect));

    }

    public void storeIntArray(String name, int[] array) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = this
                .getSharedPreferences("com.example.sid.sharedpreferencedemo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        edit.putInt("Count_" + name, array.length).commit();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i : array) {
            edit.putInt("IntValue_" + name + count++, i).commit();
        }
        edit.commit();
    }

    public int[] getFromPrefs(String name) {
        int[] ret;
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.sid.sharedpreferencedemo",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int count = prefs.getInt("Count_" + name, 0);
        ret = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ret[i] = prefs.getInt("IntValue_" + name + i, i);
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you open the app your `list` variable gets initialized to all ones. You need to load the list from shared preferences into your `list` variable not into the `isCorrect` array, because that is where you take the values from when you update the list stored in shared preferences on the click of a button.

Or in onCreate do:

```
list = isCorrect;
```

and I think it should work.

Comment: One last problem that I can't work out. When starting from the beginning, the variable isCorrect  equals []. So it crashes because there's nothing in there. How would I initialise this  without ruining the rest of the code? Thanks!

Comment: I should also say this happens when I also did your first suggestion. I also tried to make list static and it still didn't work. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions you can try.

**Solution 1**

make your int array static, and refer to the Activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   public static int[] list = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

public void startAQuestion(View view){ 
.
.
```

How to use

```
SecondActivity.list[tappedQuestionmark]=2;
```

**Solution 2**
use the savedInstance to pass your array

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    outState.putSerializable("list ", list);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     list = savedInstanceState.getSerializable("list ");

     if(list  != null)
     {
          //Do something with list 
     }

}
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: Hi many thanks for your reply! The first solution almost worked but still got overwritten when I closed the app and picked another box. What I mean is when I started the app the array was {1,1,1,1,1,1} I make 1 and 3 go to 2 as follows {1,2,1,2,1,1} then I would close the app and open again and make 0 go to 2 then it would show {2,1,1,1,1,1}. The second solution, android studio says they are incompatible types? I would be very grateful if you have any hints for either of them. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I had no undestood. So take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175880/how-can-i-store-an-integer-array-in-sharedpreferences