# reading a long type from a text file in Java

Tags: java, long-integer, stringtokenizer, numberformatexception

i'm trying to read long types from a text file with using `readLine()` method of `BufferedReader` class and then i parse the first token (which is long type number) with using `StringTokenizer` but i'm facing with an exception error which is `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

this is an example of my text file;

```
2764841629  Quaroten Ilen
1398844030  Orden Nenama
1185252727  Inja Nenaptin
2370429126  Quaren Inaja
1502141743  Otin Una
1993687334  Quarwennaja Nenoten
1015934104  Polen Meritna
2363674760  Otja Ie
1904629749  Neninin Ordja
3047965620  Algnaja Nenja
```

here is the code i read from a text file and assing the long value to my long variable

```
private void registerData() throws FileNotFoundException{
    try {

        String regPatName;
        String regPatSurname;
        long regPatID;


        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src\\assignment_3\\injuredPersonList.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String line;

        while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null) {

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

            while(st.hasMoreTokens()){

                regPatID = Long.parseLong(st.nextToken());
                regPatName = st.nextToken();
                regPatSurname = st.nextToken();

                Patient regPatient = new Patient(regPatName, regPatSurname, regPatID);
                hashMethod(regPatient);
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(personTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}

private void hashMethod(Patient regPatient){

    Long idPat = new Long(regPatient.getPatientID());
    int keyID;

    keyID = (int) Math.sqrt(Integer.parseInt(idPat.toString().substring(0, 5) + idPat.toString().substring(5, 10))) % (50000);

    System.out.println(keyID);

}
```

and finally this the error which i'm facing;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2481765933   Otna"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:419)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:468)
    at assignment_3.personTest.registerData(personTest.java:58)
    at assignment_3.personTest.<init>(personTest.java:33)
    at assignment_3.personTest$1.run(personTest.java:161)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

i will be very appreciated if you can help me and also thanks anyway.

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace you're getting. Also, providing a sample text file might be a good idea.

Comment: ok i will edit my post immediately

Comment: Isn't your input file tab separated by any chance? Tab character != space character. Try initialising your string tokenizer without specifying a delimiter. (It defaults to all whitespace.)

Comment: make sure you're passing the right field to Long.parseLong(). System.out.println(st.nextToken())

Comment: @biziclop thanks for advice but now it gives java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2481765933"

Comment: @Jay yes i passing the right field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a tab character instead of spaces to separate your fields. Add the tab to your set of delimiters (`" \t"`).

Also, always close your streams and readers in a finally block (only the outermost one must be closed: closing the BufferedReader will close the InputStreamReader, which will close the FileInputStream).

Comment: thanks for suggestion but nothing changed except it throws java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2481765933". input string doesnt contain the other token anymore

Comment: This String is a valid long representation, and I parse it without any problem. Are you sure it doesn't contain a bizarre character that would look like an ASCII digit but isn't one?

Comment: well it gives the error when it reads the first line. i check the first one thousand lines for if it contains a bizarre character but not.

Comment: Add this snippet to your code: `String s = st.nextToken(); for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {System.out.print(" " + (int) c);} System.out.println(); regPatID = Long.parseLong(s);` and tell us what is printed just before the exception is thrown.

Comment: it gives "50 52 56 49 55 54 53 57 51 51" and `exception is Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Otna"`

Comment: and this is my first line `2481765933 Otna Orda`

Comment: You're trying to parse "Otna" as a long now. Are you sure you replaced `regPatID = Long.parseLong(st.nextToken();` with `regPatID = Long.parseLong(s);`?

Comment: i guess we are looking wrong place cause i tried just reading and printing the numbers in txt and it worked. so there is no problem about parsing reading etc. but in main code which i posted i pass an object to hashMethod() i guess there is the problem but i couldnt find it everything seems ok_?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, adding the tab as a delimiter fixed the original problem, but you now have an exception in another part of the code.

Comment: i'm sure the problem is in `hashMethod(Patient regPatient)` cause when i delete the code which i call `hashMethod()` everything works perfect!

Comment: Then investigate. Read the exception message carefully, and use a debugger, or traces in the code, to discover what is wrong.

Comment: well finally i realized i'm using Integer parser in hashMethod and this stupid thing took my 2 hours to realize... pfff. by the way thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly you're trying to parse a non-numeric string, the stack trace shows it: `2481765933   Otna`. You should split the input and parse the numeric part, something like this:

```
String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
regPatID = Long.parseLong(data[0]);
regPatName = data[1];
regPatSurname = data.length == 3 ? data[2] : "";
```

The above is much simpler than using `StringTokenizer`. In fact, the usage of `StringTokenizer` is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983856/why-is-stringtokenizer-deprecated), practically deprecated - nowadays, the preferred way to parse a string is either using the `split()` method for simple cases or the `Scanner` class for complex cases.

Comment: but i use this parsing method many times when i read in integer value like when i have line "21321 otna". i guess the only problem is about long types

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong delimiter (`" "`) since your text file may contain more than one space character between tokens. `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class, don't use it unless you have a good reason to. [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) should suffice:

```
String[] result = line.split("\\s+");
regPatID = Long.parseLong(result[0]);
regPatName = result[1];
regPatSurname = result[2];
```

But I think that [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is the best fit for your problem:

```
// Java 7 try-with-resources synthax.
// If you are using Java <=6, declare a finally block after the catch 
// to close resources.
try (InputStream myFile = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("MyTextFile.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile)) {

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        regPatID = sc.nextLong();
        regPatName = sc.next();
        regPatSurname = sc.next();

        System.out.printf("%d - %s %s\n", regPatID, regPatName, regPatSurname);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    // Do something about exceptions
}
```

Both versions correctly parses your example input.

Here is a third [fully working Java 6 Version](http://ideone.com/Qrhcp).

Comment: well when i printout the "result[0]" and "regPatID" it prints the true value but again i'm facing this same stupid error. i mean it assignes truly but i dont know why i'm taking same error again.

Comment: mate i solved the problem 5 minutes ago which is about i was using `Integer.parseInt()` in `hashMethod()` as you can see in my question. and yes this works correctly as well and thanks for your help

Comment: Hi quartaela, I'm glad to be of service, since you have figured it out, you should accept @JB Nizet or Óscar López answers to reward them by helping you with your original question ;).