# java String...!

Tags: java, string

I am currently using `StringTokennizer` class to split a String into different tokenas by defined delimiter

```
 public class App {  
        public static void main(String[] args) {  

            String str = "This is String , split by StringTokenizer, created by saral";  
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);  


            System.out.println("---- Split by comma ',' ------");  
            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");  

            while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {  
                System.out.println(st2.nextElement());  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Please advise me more alternative ways to achieve this as jdk 5 support scanner and java .util, regex....!! please advise..!!

Comment: Please use a single period to end a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `java.lang.String.split()` method:

```
String str = ...;
String[] tokens = str.split(",");

for (String s: tokens)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Can I use scanner also..to achieve the same thing..!!

Comment: @SARAL `Scanner` is useful for reading a stream of characters, and `split()` for splitting it. They complement each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String str = "This is String , split by StringTokenizer, created by saral";
String[] arr = str.split(",");
```

Now, `arr` will be an array containing each comma-separated part of `str`.

Comment: Can I use Scanner class also , to achieve the same thing...!! I was trying this....    public class App1 {  
          
        public static void main(String[] args)    
        {  
             Scanner scanner =  new Scanner("This is String , split by StringTokenizer, created by saral").useDelimiter(", ");    
          
         while (scanner.hasNextLine())  ;  
             System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());    
     }    
      
      
    }  I was trying these but not getting the result ..!!please advise..!!

Answer (score 0):

`StringTokenizer` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983856/why-is-stringtokenizer-deprecated) for all practical purposes, it's there only for backwards compatibility. Use the method [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) instead, like this:

```
String[] splitted = str.split(",");
```

Now the returned `String[]` will contain the tokens.

Comment: I was looking for java regex or something new ,I want to avoid string split method and tokenizer some thing new from regex..!!

Comment: @SARAL read the documentation of `split()` in the link, it receives a regular expression as a parameter! in this simple example `","` is a regex, but it can be as complex as you want