# java string delimiter, keeping delimiter in token

Tags: java, string, delimiter

im trying to split a string but keep the delimiter at the beginning of the next token (if thats possible)

Example: I'm trying to split the string `F120LF120L` into

```
F120
L
F120
L
```

I've tried

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "F,L");
```

but that just returns

```
120
120
```

Comment: Do you want to split by 'F' and 'L' only, or also by ',' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), you can use `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "L", true);` The last parameter is a boolean that specifies that delimiters have to be returned too.

Comment: That way, F is returned separately.. not F120! For his example, the following would work: StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "L", true);

Comment: Ah, yes. Should read more carefully. :( I'll update the answer, thanks!

Comment: BTW, note to the OP, if you're splitting by tokesn, you don't need the last parameter either. That is, you're just using "L" as a token, not "F"

Comment: yeah i will be using "F" as a token, also sometimes there will be some numbers after "L" but thanks, im on the right track now to figure the rest out myself (I hope) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), for all practical purposes `StringTokenizer` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983856/why-is-stringtokenizer-deprecated) (it's still there only for backwards compatibility). This will work:

```
String delimiter = "L";
String str = "F120LF120L";
String[] splitted = str.split(delimiter);

for (String s : splitted) {
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(delimiter);
}

> F120
> L
> F120
> L
```

Comment: `str.split(delimiter);` it's returns array of `F120` without `L`

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it brute force?

```
String del = "L";
String str = "F120LLF120LLLLF12L";
int i = 0;

while (true) {
    i = str.indexOf(del, i);
    if (i == -1) break;
    String a = str.substring(0, i);
    String b = str.substring(i + del.length());
    str = a + " " + del;
    str += b.startsWith(del) || b.length() == 0 ? b : " " + b;
    i = a.length() + del.length() + 1;
}

System.out.println(str);
// Will print: F120 L L F120 L L L L F12 L
```

Comment: You must of course replace the space strings (" ") with newline strings ("\n")