# What are tokens used for in this example?

Tags: java

Can someone please tell me what the tokens are for in this code?  I've just recently discovered tokens in Java and trying to get an understanding of why they are used.  I thought tokens were used as break points, but here it almost looks like it is used to limit

```
private String printResult()
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String swimType=null;
    String length=null;
    String width=null;
    String depth=null;
    String volume=null;
    String radius=null;
    String pnlName = null;
    try {
        File resultFile = new File("Report.txt");
        Scanner resultScanner = new Scanner(resultFile);

        while(resultScanner.hasNext())
        {
            StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(resultScanner.nextLine(), ":");
            if(strToken.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                pnlName = strToken.nextToken();
                swimType = strToken.nextToken();

                if("Box".equalsIgnoreCase(swimType))
                {
                    length = strToken.nextToken();
                    width = strToken.nextToken();
                    depth = strToken.nextToken();
                    volume = strToken.nextToken();
                    result.append(createResultStr(swimType, length, width, depth, volume));
                }
                else
                {
                    radius = strToken.nextToken();
                    depth = strToken.nextToken();
                    volume = strToken.nextToken();                      
                    result.append(createResultStr(swimType, radius, depth, volume));
                }

            }               
        }
```

Comment: if you google you will find more useful resources. However here is link http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/tokens/lecture.html and http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/9802.aspx

Comment: @smit : Here I believe the question is related to `StringTokenizer`, not the traditional language tokens.

Comment: @Amar +1; Sorry my apology, I didn't gone through code.

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is deprecated.

Comment: @A.R.S. Are you sure it deprecated? I have not found anything related to it except this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983856/why-is-stringtokenizer-deprecated

Comment: Ya it is not deprecated in it's true sense, but yes it's use is discouraged and String.split's use if encouraged instead.

Answer (score 4):

Tokenizing is the process were you split up a string based on a character. You may want to split on the comma. You pass the string through the tokenizer giving ',' as the separator. Then as you read each item out of the tokenizer they are split up based on the separator. A common approach I have seen is reading a live stream. A tokenizer splits the stream on linefeed and then each line is split on commas or tabs using another tokenizer.

The processing of text often consists of parsing a formatted
input string. *Parsing*
is the division of text into a set of discrete parts, or *tokens,*
which in a certain
sequence can convey a semantic meaning. The **StringTokenizer**
class provides the first
step in this parsing process, often called the *lexer*
(lexical analyzer) or *scanner*.
**StringTokenizer**

implements the **Enumeration**
interface. Therefore,
given an input string, you can enumerate the individual tokens contained in it using **StringTokenizer**.

To use **StringTokenizer**,
you specify an input string and a string that contains delimiters.

*Delimiters* are
characters that separate tokens. Each character in the delimiters string is considered a valid delimiter—for example, **",;:"**
sets the delimiters to a
comma, semicolon, and colon. The default set of delimiters consists of
the whitespace characters: space, tab, newline, and carriage return.

The **StringTokenizer**
constructors are shown
here:

```
StringTokenizer(String str) 
StringTokenizer(String str, String delimiters) 
StringTokenizer(String str, String delimiters, boolean delimAsToken)
```

In all versions, *str*
is the string that will
be tokenized. In the first version, the default delimiters are used. In the second and third versions, *delimiters*
is a string that
specifies the delimiters. In the third version, if *delimAsToken*
is **true**,
then the delimiters are also returned as tokens when the string is parsed. Otherwise, the
delimiters are not returned.

Delimiters are not returned as tokens by the first two forms. Once you have created a **StringTokenizer**
object, the **nextToken(
)** method is used to extract consecutive tokens. The **hasMoreTokens(
)** method returns **true**
while there are more tokens to be extracted. Since **StringTokenizer**
implements **Enumeration**,
the

**hasMoreElements( )** and
**nextElement( )** methods
are also implemented, and they act the same as **hasMoreTokens(
)** and **nextToken(
)**, respectively.

Here is an example that creates a **StringTokenizer**
to parse
"key=value" pairs. Consecutive sets of "key=value" pairs are separated by
a semicolon.

```
// Demonstrate StringTokenizer.
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

class STDemo {
    static String in = "title=Java-Samples;" +
        "author=Emiley J;" +
        "publisher=java-samples.com;" +
        "copyright=2007;";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in, "=;");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String key = st.nextToken();
            String val = st.nextToken();
            System.out.println(key + "\t" + val);
        }
    }
}
```

The output from this program is shown here:

```
title Java-samples 
author Emiley J 
publisher java-samples.com 
copyright 2007
```

**Note**
if delimiter is null, this constructor does not throw an exception. However, trying to invoke other methods on the resulting StringTokenizer may result in a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: you really did your homework but better you give nice formatting to your examples.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention about NullPointerException, Add this to your, it will help understand other people.

Comment: @smit :You meant about the case when delimiter is null, right? If yes, then I have made the edit and added a Note at last.

Comment: Now It seems to be complete answer, However take your time and format your answer lilbit.

Comment: Wow that is one great post you have there. +1 indeed.

Answer (score 0):

seems like an input file contains data in certain structure and the `:` is a delimiter, so it reads data token by token and assigns values to the variables with the further append to some `result` string