# trouble in java, splitting strings

Tags: java, string, split

I want to scan a sentence that the user types, but I want to scan the words separately and then perform the actions depending on the words the user has put.

```
}else if(choice.equals("load")){
  System.out.println("Enter the name of the file:");
  String name = input.next();
  loadFile(name);
```

what I want is the user to type "load file.txt" directly

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: Show us some input and expected output. You can split string by `String.split("\\s+")` for whitespaces

Comment: this is one case of my code, so for each one of them i need the user to type the full sentence of what he wants and with one scan the program will execute.

Comment: I basically answered that question in my comment under [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923379/i-have-an-issue-using-tokens-scanning-multiple-inputs-and-executing-them-at-the).

Comment: @smit the input should be "load file.txt" and the program will execute that file without the need for the user to firstly type if he wants to load and then asked again what file he wants to load

Comment: Please read up on [how to ask good questions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) before trying this again. You'll get better answers if you ask better questions.

Comment: @AngeloMico You really need to revise your question. Your headline saying something, Your code says something else and you want something different than those two.

Comment: @jlordo i know, i just have no clue how to use that string splitting , should i used it after i scan it or what?give me an example

Comment: @AngeloMico just take a look on my answer

Comment: just like in my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923379/i-have-an-issue-using-tokens-scanning-multiple-inputs-and-executing-them-at-the#comment19195130_13923379). First read the line than split that string. I even have the code for you in [that comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923379/i-have-an-issue-using-tokens-scanning-multiple-inputs-and-executing-them-at-the#comment19195130_13923379)

Comment: @jlordo i know you did man and thanks for that but i didn't know how to  do this ---> if(input.contains("load")) sorry if I am a pain in the ass with the stupid questions,i just got here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to write a small code for you may be this can help you a little bit

```
    public class Tester2 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean state = true;
        while(state) {

            System.out.println("Please enter your text");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            if(input.contains("load")) {
                String fileName = getFileName(input);
                if(fileName != "" || fileName!= null) {
                    load(fileName);
                }
            }else{

            }

        }

    }

    private static String getFileName(String input) {
        String values[] = input.split("\\s+");
        String fileName = "";
        for(String s : values) {
            if(s.indexOf(".") > 0) {
                fileName = s;
                break;
            }
        }
        return fileName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Whenever you have questions, feel free to ask

Comment: ,yup i think its kind of what i want i just dont get this : for(String s : values) { if(s.indexOf(".") > 0) { fileName = s; break; why did you do this?

Comment: for(String s : values) ==> iteration/loop over the values
 if(s.indexOf(".") > 0) ==> here we want to which word has an extension in another which word contains(".")
if we get one we passe it to fileName then we do not need anymore to continue (break). 

If your satisfy with my answer just vote up and accept it

Comment: ok,one more thing,I need to have some other options other than "load" like "inspect" an other class etc.. should I continue with this way? put an "else" and carry on with the next option?and do i need to do the thing i asked above again for each of the options i have?

Comment: You can do it in the same. but use else if(conditions){} try write a litte method where you can some some codes to avoid the repetition

Comment: yeah "else if" , alright man thanks ! I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer though, sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's too long for a comment, and I don't really understand what your last comment means. Here's some sample code. Try it with inputs like

- load filename.txt
- load foo bar baz
- save foo
- whatever ...

  ```
  System.out.println("What would you like to do");
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  String[] input = line.split("\\s+");
  if (input[0].equals("load")) {
      for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
          System.out.println("Token #" + i + " after load: " + input[i]);
      }
  } else {
      System.out.println("You did not enter load, I ignore your input");
  }
  ```

If you have a question about the behavior or anything else: feel free to leave a comment.