# How to break a string when a word was found

Tags: java, string

I have a data in my String object  which is like below

```
Scanner Inlist 1,2,3
 Resolved scan set NotEqual to  Non Scan Set
 Area of intrest equal to Total Intrest
 Initial responder Inlist enter values
```

Now when I read each line if I  found words (Inlist ,NotEqual,Inlist ) then it need to break the line and need toread the next line.

```
Output would be:

Scanner 
Resolved scan set
Area of intrest
Initial responder
```

Till now what i have tried is

```
String filterstringobj=promtchild.toString();
StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(filterstringobj,"");
while(str.hasMoreTokens())
{
    String Inlistremove=str.nextToken("InList");
    if(Inlistremove.length()!=0)
    {                       
         System.out.println(Inlistremove);
         if(Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("InList") && 
            Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("NotEqual") && 
            Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("Equal")
           )
         {
            System.out.println(Inlistremove);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is storing the string data                                 Scanner Inlist 1,2,3
Resolved scan set NotEqual to  Non Scan Set
Area of intrest equal to Total Intrest
 Initial responder Inlist enter values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line:

```
StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(filterstringobj," ");
```

instead of

```
StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(filterstringobj,"");
```

**EDIT**
Ok then watch the following Demo code :

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
class  WordsFromString
{
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        String data = "Scanner Inlist 1,2,3\n"+
                      "Resolved scan set NotEqual to  Non Scan Set\n"+
                      "Area of intrest equal to Total Intrest\n"+
                      "Initial responder Inlist enter values";
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(data,"\n",true);
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String sLine = tokenizer.nextToken();
            StringTokenizer tokenizerWord = new StringTokenizer(sLine," ",true);
            while (tokenizerWord.hasMoreElements())
            {
                String word = tokenizerWord.nextToken();
                if ("Inlist".equals(word) || "NotEqual".equals(word) || "Inlist".equals(word) || "equal".equals(word))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    output.append(word);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried with that either, it is just breaking the lines. but i want to read the data until the String delimiters were found. how can i achive that ?

Comment: what `filterstringobj` is storing??

Answer (score 3):

You have a big flaw in your logic:

Looking at your `if` I see

```
if(Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("InList")&&Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("NotEqual")&&...
```

How can `Inlistremove` ever be equal to `"InList"` **AND** be equal to `"NotEqual"` at the same time? Are you looking for **OR**? That would be `||`

Answer (score 1):

Very flexible, only one line:

```
public static String parseLine(String line){
    return line.replaceAll("(?i)(inlist|notequal|equal).*", "");
}

public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(parseLine("Resolved scan set NotEqual to  Non Scan Set"));
    System.out.println(parseLine("Area of intrest equal to Total Intrest"));
    System.out.println(parseLine("Initial responder Inlist enter values"));
}
```

Will print:

> Resolved scan set
>
> Area of intrest
>
> Total Intrest Initial responder

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use StringTokenizer.
Plese see [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983856/why-is-stringtokenizer-deprecated) to know why?

Instead of StringTokenizer you can use regex to match the parts of string which you don't need and replace them with empty string.

Comment: -1 You should put this as a comment, it doesn't answer the question

Comment: really bad thinking, its not replacing, its about ignoring.

Comment: I cant yet add comments. I can add comments to my own answers only.

Comment: @fmsf 2nd paragraph does answer the question, which is about removing end of line after it matches a keyword, before printing it... Though it could of course provide regexp to do it. Also first paragraph raises a very valid point about `StringTokenizer`, with supporting link.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems in your code:

```
StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(filterstringobj,"");
```

which should be

```
StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(filterstringobj," ");
```

Second is here:

```
if(Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("InList") && 
            Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("NotEqual") && 
            Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("Equal")
           )
```

which should be:

```
if(Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("InList") ||
            Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("NotEqual") || 
            Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("Equal")
           )
```

The third one is, how will you move to the next line of the string array? You have to change the code slightly to incorporate moving to another string to parse.

For that, I suggest you to create a function:

```
public static void Parse(String s){ 
   String filterstringobj=s;
   StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(filterstringobj," ");
   while(str.hasMoreTokens())
   {
       String Inlistremove=str.nextToken("InList");
       if(Inlistremove.length()!=0)
       {                       
           System.out.println(Inlistremove);
            if(Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("InList") ||
               Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("NotEqual") ||
               Inlistremove.equalsIgnoreCase("Equal")
            )
           {
               System.out.println(Inlistremove);
               return;
           }
      }
   }
}
```

and in the `main()` method you do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] array = new String[3];
    array[0] = "Resolved scan set NotEqual to  Non Scan Set";
    array[1] = "Area of intrest equal to Total Intrest";
    array[2] = "Initial responder Inlist enter values";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          Parse(array[i]);
    }
}
```