# Splitting a string with delimiters for Strings containing other characters with the same delimiter

Tags: java, regex, split, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to split a string like the one : "@WWP2-@POLUXDATAWWP3-TTTTTW@K826" to extract the @WWP2-@POLUXDATAWWP3-TTTTTW and the 826 strings
when executing the snippet :

```
String expression = "@WWP2-@POLUXDATAWWP3-TTTTTW@K826";
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expression, "@K");
            if (tokenizer.countTokens() > 0) {
                while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
                }
            }
```

while expecting the result to be

WWP2-POLUXDATAWWP3-TTTTTW
826

I'm getting:

WWP2-
POLUXDATAWWP3-TTTTTW
826

Any idea on how to get the exact two strings?

Comment: So finally, you want to split by `@K`, and remove the remaining `@`, don't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    String[] str = expression.split("@K");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
```

Try String#split("@K");

Output:

```
[@WWP2-@POLUXDATAWWP3-TTTTTW, 826]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String expression = "@WWP2-@POLUXDATAWWP3-TTTTTW@K826";

String [] strArr = expression.split("@K");

for( int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++ ) {
    System.out.println( strArr[i] );
}
```

The `StringTokenizer` splits the string on all the single characters in the delimiter string, i.e. on `@` *and* `K`.

Also see [Why is StringTokenizer deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983856/why-is-stringtokenizer-deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

`StringTokenizer` will use the given delimiter parameter as a set of chars if it contains more than one char. In your case, it will split your string by `@` and by `K`, while `K` must not necessarily follow `@`.