# String operations:Split

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string consisting of file separators; e.g. "Bancs\Bancs_CP_P&MB.xml".

I want to separate the string based on "\".

Here's what I'm trying:

```
public class Stringoperations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            String TestCaseName = "Bancs" + fileSeparator + "Bancs_CP_P&MB.xml";
            String[] tukde = TestCaseName.split("\\");
            System.out.println(tukde[0]);
            System.out.println(tukde[1]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("here");
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not working.

Comment: What is not working about it?

Comment: Splitting string with "\"

Comment: You can make use of `StringTokenizer` for splitting.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or getting exception?

Comment: Ya.. StringTokenizer dows work for me... Thanks

Comment: @Maximin `StringTokenizer` is deprecated.

Comment: @Maximin , there is no error and no exception. But its not working.@sweta you should put fileSeparator inside split method. And try.

Comment: @squiguy I didn't found as deprecated. It is still in [java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). Didn't found anything stating it deprecated.

Comment: @Maximin I'm not trying to point fingers, just hopefully offering some advice.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983856/why-is-stringtokenizer-deprecated

Comment: @squiguy Went through it. It's not deprecated. It is a legacy class.

Answer (score 1):

First: add a `e.printStackTrace();` or something similar to your catch block, so you'll see what's actually wrong:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
```

A back slash in Java string literals allows you place special chars into a string:

```
String withTab = "a\tb";
```

would print as `"a     b"`. To get a backslash in a Java string you need to escape it:

```
String withBackslash = "a\\b";
```

So this is what you done in the split invocation: you passed one java string back slash. Since `String.split()` evaluates the passed string a regular expression [(Java Doc for String.split())](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), the back slash is treated as a RegEx. Backslash has a special meaning in regular expressions and cannot appear alone ([Java Doc for Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)). If you want a literal back slash you need to escape the back slash again:

```
String[] tukde = TestCaseName.split("\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, putting that code into IntelliJ IDEA causes it to fuss at me with an illegal escape sequence.  You have to escape the escape, so you'd be using `\\\\` as valid backslash escape syntax.

Second, you should be splitting on `fileSeparator`, not an arbitrary backslash.  The backslash actually varies from system to system (e.g. I'm on Linux Mint, and my separators are all forward slashes).

```
String[] tukde = TestCaseName.split(fileSeparator);
```

As a further note, there's no exceptions here that could be thrown (save for runtime), and blindly catching all exceptions isn't a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {

        String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        String TestCaseName = "Bancs"+fileSeparator+"Bancs_CP_P&MB.xml";
        String[] tukde = TestCaseName.split("\\\\");

        System.out.println(tukde[0]);
        System.out.println(tukde[1]);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("here");
        }
    }
```

Out put :-

```
Bancs
Bancs_CP_P&MB.xml
here
```

Answer (score 0):

What platform or OS are you working on. Maybe your default file separator is not "\". Try this :

```
public class Stringoperations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            String TestCaseName = "Bancs" + fileSeparator + "Bancs_CP_P&MB.xml";
            String[] tukde = TestCaseName.split(fileSeparator); //This uses the default separator returned by System.getProperty
            System.out.println(tukde[0]);
            System.out.println(tukde[1]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("here");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Also as Makoto points out if you are bent on using "\" to split you need to use "\\" and not "\"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String pattern = Pattern.quote(System.getProperty("file.separator"));
String[] splittedFileName = fileName.split(pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Stringoperations {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        String TestCaseName = "Bancs" + fileSeparator + "Bancs_CP_P&MB.xml";
        String[] tukde = TestCaseName.split("\\\\");
        System.out.println(tukde[0]);
        System.out.println(tukde[1]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("here");
    }
}
}
```

try this