# string tokenizing from textview

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have TextView with text that changed dynamically. 
i want tokenizing this text with delimiter space " " and send to another textview

this is my code

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getId()==R.id.button5){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Tokenizing.class);

        String test = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6)).getText().toString();
        String result = null;
        StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(test," ");
            while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String st3 = st2.nextToken();
                System.out.println(st3);

                result = st3;
        }
        i.putExtra("result", result);
        startActivity(i);
        Log.i("Test Klik Next", result);
```

but i have just last word in the textview.
text before tokenizing:

```
        Examples of paradoxes can be humorous and confusing
```

text after tokenizing:

```
        confusing
```

where is the part of my coding is wrong?

Comment: It's not *wrong* anywhere, it's doing what you told it to do. What do you expect the `result` variable to contain? At the moment it just contains the last word.

Comment: Your `result` is getting updated in the loop each time. And will have the last word at the end. if you want to do something with each word, do so in the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting the result every time you read a new token

```
result = st3;
```

So it's always equal to the last value.  Change the type of result from `String` to [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and just build it as you go

```
 result.append(st3 + " "); //re-adding the space as the StringTokenizer will remove it
```

Then after the `StringTokenizer` loop just get the built `String` using `result.toString()`

---

**Why not `result += st3`?**

Some other answers suggest you do this.  The reason not to do this is that in Java, `String` is immutable.  This means they can't be changed so any time you append two `String` objects, a new `String` object is created.
So every step through the loop you are creating a new `String` object which is inefficient and unnecessary.  `StringBuilder` is not immutable and `String`s can be appended to it without the overhead of creating new objects every time.

**StringTokenizer**

Worth noting -as @RGraham said in the comments- that this class is deprecated.  This means it's no longer in common use, use of it is discouraged and it could be removed at some point.
[More information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983856/why-is-stringtokenizer-deprecated).

**Tokens - in or out**

As other answers assumed the opposite of me and after discussion on one of said answers and on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215227/should-answers-which-add-unspecified-effects-be-downvoted/215233?noredirect=1#215233), I feel I need to clarify this.  I
'm not sure if your intention was to get rid of the tokens (in this case spaces " ") and end up with

```
Examplesofparadoxescanbehumorousandconfusing
```

or to replace them when outputting the final `String` and get out what you put in.  So I assumed you wanted to preserve the original meaning and replace them.  Otherwise a quicker way to get the result above would be to simply skip all the tokenizing and do

```
test.replaceAll(" ","");
```

Comment: May also be worth noting that StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons and its use is discouraged in new code

Comment: replace `String result = null;` with `StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();` and replace `result = st3` with the code I suggested in my post.  Lastly, replace `i.putExtra("result", result);` with `i.putExtra("result", result.toString());`

Comment: yeah work bro
i try your code and i add result.append(st3+'\n');

and the result like this
Examples
of
paradoxes
can
be
humorous
and
confusing

thanks bro, and next process i want to remove punctuation and get that text to lowercase.

can you help me again?

Comment: Look at the methods of `String` called `toLowerCase` and `replaceAll`

Answer (score 0):

```
  while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String st3 = st2.nextToken();
                    System.out.println(st3);

                    result = st3;  // Everytime you are reassigning result to some other String
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`result = st3;` by (initialize `String result=" ";`) 
`result+=st3+" "`

and then replace 
`i.putExtra("result", result);` with `i.putExtra("result", result.trim());`

Try this , it will show perfect result.

You can also do this `result.append(st3+" ");` and then `i.putExtra("result", result.trim());`

Comment: this will return " Examplesofparadoxescanbehumorousandconfusing" and will need to create 8 separate `String` objects

Comment: ok it will ease add a space in this manner result+=st3+" " . It will be solved